# Error importing currency data from hotbit to google sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, currency, price

Im making a sheet with currencies data from coinmarketcap.
I could import bitcoin price successfuly using this code: =INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/","//td"),1,1)

But when I try to import from hotbit using:
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.hotbit.io/exchange?symbol=PORNROCKET_USDT","//td"),1,1)

I get an error: Could not fetch url

How can I get pornrocket price from hotbit to google sheets?
Before you ask, the reason I don't get pornrocket price from coinmarketcap is because I have bought from hotbit and the prices differs a lot.

Comment: I think the request is blocked by Cloudflare that you may consider fetch with a script.

Answer (score 0):

For `https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/`, you can retrieve data by parsing the json, try

```
function test2(){
  var url='https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/'
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.split('<script type="application/ld+json">')[1].split('</script>')[0]
  var data = JSON.parse(jsonString)
  Logger.log(data.currentExchangeRate.price)
}
```

but with hobbit, since the page is built entirely in javascript and the site first checks the browser you are using, there is no way. The data is downloaded by asynchronous method.